# What makes a band last long?

Tags: bands

I don't think the titles's correct for this.

If you see, Aerosmith or Rolling Stones, or some bands that had never been apart from each other (that stick to the lineup) is kinda old now, I mean, they're like 40 years old (or more) for a band. Well, i've research and found Golden Earring as the oldest band still exist.

What makes them stay in the band? What makes them last up until now?

Comment: Unless there's some research out there (don't know of any) this is one of these questions where an answer can only be opinion based, so probably of topic. I find it an interesting subject though, so I'll give my two cents. From the cases I can think of, one or more members of the band with a very strong creative vision seems to be a predominant factor.

Answer (score 3):

Being in a band means sharing most of your time with your co-workers. There could be good times and bad times because people change. The Beatles broke up because of that, suddenly they had different opinions about everything (the songs, the public image, politics, money, etc.).

They got together being teenagers, but when they became adults each one wanted something different.

The Rolling Stones had a lot low points:

- Late 60s: Brian Jones was heavily on drugs, he was a drag for the band and they decided to fire him.
- Late 70s: Keith got deeply into drugs. Mick took the financial and artistic direction of the band, while Keith got into problems with authorities wherever he went.
- During the 80s: Mick wanted to make a solo career and Keith, recovered from his addictions, wanted to record another album and go on tour. They finally got together again under a business agreement and they have contact with each other as less as possible.

Aerosmith: They had a lot of break-ups and reunions.

Van Halen: Except the two Van Halen brothers, everybody is disposable.

Most of the time the problems are:

- Heavy use of drugs
- Disagreements about tour time vs. free time
- Disagreements about distribution of money
- Expectation of solo careers.
- Artistic disagreements.

If band members avoid these 5 issues, there is a chance that they can got together a long time.

Comment: I'm still salty that Mike Anthony isn't in Van Halen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Take an example of Queen: they didn't last long because their lead singer died

Live. That's what make them last long.

Or maybe they didn't get along and decided to break up.